# Communicating with hardware inside windows driver

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

Let's say I have a device connected to my computer appearing as a serial port to the operating system.

Can I "CreateFile" to this serial port inside a windows driver, or is there another way to write and read from a device. I try to grasp how exactly a driver communicates with the hardware - and as far as I assume one must obtain a handle to the resource and the only way I know is asking the operating system (createfile) to return a handle to that resource by specifying a path to it.

Am I right, or am I mistaken something?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an existing driver then yes, the device will appear as a file to other components of the OS, as well as user-space programs.

If there is no driver then the device will appear as whatever resources the hardware presents (memory-mapped IO registers, etc) to a device driver with a matching hardware or compatibility ID. That is, the driver for a device is chosen based on a driver with the closest matching ID.

Comment: So, if i am the driver developer for that very hardware connected via usb to the computer for which is no driver avaible yet  i would use corresponding methods provided by e.g. the windows driver kit to establish a communication channel, right? What methods are typically used to read and write from a memory mapped io register? Can I just use MmMapIoSpace and then declare a pointer to that resource?

Comment: Yes, you would use functions from the WDK. I don't know enough to answer you more specifically than that, my experience with windows drivers has all been for virtual devices (a classic COM port served by a network connection and work on a media changer device that used disk images).